# What statement query should I use?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to look for a specific class, and if I enter the section and subject in a search bar, for example: Jade and English; What statement query should I use? Note that there are lots of section and subjects in the database.

```
Table name = Class | Db name = DB 
+--------+---------+------------+
| name   | section | subject    |
+--------+---------+------------+
| Arvin  | Rizal   | Math       |
| Kate   | Rizal   | Math       |
| Andrei | Jade    | English    |
| Adriel | Jade    | English    |
| Gian   | Banaba  | Science    |
| Floyd  | Banaba  | Science    |
| Jose   | Lapu    | Values     |
| Noah   | Lapu    | Values     |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: This is very basic SQL. Please take a tutorial before asking

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Class WHERE section = 'Jade' AND subject = 'English'` maybe?

Comment: I dont want to get the specific value. Since, there are a lot of section and subjects to put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
post form with field name section and subject
$section=$_POST['section'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];

SELECT * FROM Class WHERE section like '%$section%' AND subject like '%$subject%'
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are trying to `Select` a row from your database.
This statement should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM Class WHERE name = 'Jade' AND subject = 'English';
```

Edit: I just re-read your question and thought it might be about implementing a search form using PHP. In this case, you should have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/index.html).